Permission masking at boot
Sick of wasting time with AIs that say completely contradictory things, here I am.
I am trying to mount at boot an exfat storage device mainly used to save media & docs but with some scripts to execute as well.
As an administrative user I want to have full rights on files and directories on the device (rwx) without authenticating myself except once at login (or at re-mount in case of unmounting). Groups and others will have less permissions.
It seems that using fstab, fmask and dmask is the way to go and I thought a dmask of 0022 for rwxr-xr-x and an fmask of 0033 for rwxr--r-- would be ok (thanks to this, this, AIs and other sources). The resulting fstab line (considering that I am user 1000) would be:
file_system  mount_point exfat   defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0033,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8 0   0
Can you please confirm that both my reasoning, the mask values and the fstab line are correct?
Thanks.

Wouldn't it be easier to just try? Should be quicker than composing your post. That said, looks good. Using dmask=0002, fmask=0113 for drwxrwxr-x and .rw-rw-r-- in a similar way. I also have a different group for the mount (storage) to have more fine-grained options.

Ty: I'll let you know how it goes... Me just trying rarely works or leads to satisfactory outcomes. I prefer understanding stuff, asking expert advice and then maybe make attempts by myself.
I'm also wary of playing with users/groups (let alone creating new ones) bc I'd rather keep things as simple as possible.

Well it worked. Yet some permissions on a twin fstab mounted external drive got mysteriously upscaled as well without any manual modification (now I can create/edit files without authentication there too). I'm giving up on understanding linux behavior...
